# CoreMIDI works on iOS and MacOS, but not on PCs or Line6 Mobilizer

Tags: ios, midi, coremidi

I'm using PGMidi for MIDI implementation in my iOS app.  It works great.  However, I have received two reports that the messages are not getting through in certain cases.  The first is over wireless with Ableton Live, on a PC.  I know that it works fine over wireless on a Mac with Ableton. The other situation is with a Line6 Mobilizer II.  The device shows up in the MIDI ports, but does not register any MIDI messages.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the data that makes it unrecognizable to a PC?  Any ideas what this could be?

Here's the basic MIDI send stuff (mostly straight from PGMidi)

```
-(void)noteOn:(NSUInteger)voice note:(NSUInteger)note{

if(voice == 1){

    UInt8 status = 144 + (UInt8)chordMIDIChannel;
    const UInt8 noteOn[]  = { status, (UInt8)note, chordMIDIVelocity };

    if(chordMIDIDest)[chordMIDIDest sendBytes:noteOn size:sizeof(noteOn)];
    else [midi virtualPortSend:noteOn size:sizeof(noteOn)];

}else{
    UInt8 status = 144 + (UInt8)leadMIDIChannel;
    const UInt8 noteOn[]  = { status, (UInt8)note, leadMIDIVelocity };

    if(leadMIDIDest)[leadMIDIDest sendBytes:noteOn size:sizeof(noteOn)];
    else[midi virtualPortSend:noteOn size:sizeof(noteOn)];
}
```

}

and the PGMidiDestination send bytes:

```
- (void) sendBytes:(const UInt8*)bytes size:(UInt32)size
{
assert(size < 65536);
Byte packetBuffer[size+100];
MIDIPacketList *packetList = (MIDIPacketList*)packetBuffer;
MIDIPacket     *packet     = MIDIPacketListInit(packetList);
packet = MIDIPacketListAdd(packetList, sizeof(packetBuffer), packet, 0, size, bytes);

[self sendPacketList:packetList];
}

- (void) sendPacketList:(const MIDIPacketList *)packetList
{
// Send it
OSStatus s = MIDISend(midi.outputPort, endpoint, packetList);
NSLogError(s, @"Sending MIDI");
}
```

Comment: "I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the data that makes it unrecognizable to a PC?" -- that's a big assumption. MIDI data is arranged the same way regardless of what device you're talking to. Much more likely to be a config issue, or you're sending to the wrong output port.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the code looks correct, but I would suspect that you have something going on with the endpoint that you are using.

An easy test would be to simply send your data to EVERY endpoint on your system and see what happens, that way you'll know if it's your data or your configuration of the endpoint.

Replace (temporarily) the code in your sendPacketList function, with this, and see if you get data at those destinations:

```
    // Send it everywhere
    for (ItemCount index = 0; index < MIDIGetNumberOfDestinations(); ++index)
    {
        MIDIEndpointRef outputEndpoint = MIDIGetDestination(index);

        if (outputEndpoint)
        {
            OSStatus s = MIDISend(midi.outputPort, outputEndpoint, packetList);
            // check s for errors
        }
    }
```

I've used the code above to send to MIDI Network destinations as well as MIDI Mobilizer II devices, and it worked.